# How to add assetlinks.json in Angular project for Android App Links?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Please guys help me!
I don’t know where and what folder to add assetlinks.json and what needs to be written further for it to work.
I have a SHA256 key and application applicationId, for sure this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 steps.

1. Create new folder in src, add `assetlinks.json` in that newly created folder under src.
2. Now in assets array in angular.json add path as `"src/foldercreated"` similar to what you do with other assets like images and css or scss.

URI to assetlinks.json: `https://{your_domain}/folderCreated/assetlinks.json`

#angular